# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (780,1080) (780,1080,3)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, numpy

I'm using opencv and numpy for image processing.

I am thresholding an image and then doing some processing on it and later I mask it with the original image.

I do threshold like this (step1):

```
    ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray,210,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
```

Then I assign `thresh1` to `img` (step2):

```
    img = thresh1
```

and I mask like this (step3):

```
    final = img&cv2.cvtColor(less, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

However, with this I get the following error on step3:

```
    operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (780,1080) (780,1080,3)
```

If I replace step2 with:

```
    cv2.imwrite("2.png", thresh1)
    img = cv2.imread("2.png")
```

Then everything works fine. I can't understand the difference in actually saving and then reading the same image from disk vs. just assigning `img` to `thresh1`

Is there a way I can avoid writing and reading the image from disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for why the file write/read makes it work, `img` / `thresh` is a single-channel image. When you write it to the png format, it is being converted to RGB (or rather BGR). So when you reload it, it's now a BGR image which matches the shape of your converted `less` image.

Ah, so as berak said, you will probably be fine with `img&less` before you convert less to RGB.

Alternatively:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(thresh1, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

and the remainder of your code should work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. the alternative approach was the path with least resistance :)

Answer (score 0):

both operands for `&` need the same num of channels. you might want to skip the `cv2.cvtColor()` and use `img & less` directly

Comment: remove `cv2.cvtColor` on less fixes this problem but further messes up the processing I'm performing on `final`